# Дублирование в связанной таблице,есть идеи?

Tags: php, mysql, redbeanphp

Проблема : выводит в цикле только статус "Новый" related_id с номером product_id 1 связанную таблицу,Product_id 2 и 3 отображает тоже как новый, а долно писать ожидание и старый..

Таблица **product_status**

```html
CREATE TABLE `product_status` (
  `product_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `related_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `product_status` (`product_id`, `related_id`, `id`) VALUES
(1, 'Новый', 1),
(2, 'Старый', 2),
(3, 'Ожидание', 3);

ALTER TABLE `product_status`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `product_id` (`product_id`);

ALTER TABLE `product_status`
  MODIFY `id` int(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
COMMIT;
```

Связанно с таблицей **new**

```html
CREATE TABLE `new` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status_id` int(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `new` (`id`, `name`, `status_id`) VALUES
(1, 'Чипсы', 1),
(2, 'Кола', 2);

ALTER TABLE `new`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `status_id` (`status_id`);

ALTER TABLE `new`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
COMMIT;
```

Файл maincontroller

```html
<?php

namespace app\controllers;


use site\App;
use site\Cache;

class MainController extends AppController {

    public function indexAction(){
        $products = \R::findAll('product');
        $productstatus = \R::findOne('product_status');
        $stat = \R::getAll("SELECT * FROM product_status JOIN new ON new.status_id = product_status.product_id WHERE product_status.related_id = ?",[$productstatus->related_id]);


$this->set(compact('stat')); //вывожу переменную
```

Файл index

```html
<?php foreach ($stat as $item): ?>
    <?php if ($products): ?>


        <section class="content">
            <?php foreach ($products as $product): ?><!-- Контент -->
            <article class="block">
                <div class="block--name">
                    <div class="button"><gg><a href="#"><?= $product->title; ?></a></gg></div>
                    <div class="rating">рейгтин</div>
                    <div class="status"> Status bar</div></div>
                <div class="block--photo">фото</div>
                <div class="block--info">
                    <div class="daterat">                               <!-- Дата / рейтинг -->


                        <div class="rat">                                 <!-- рейтинг -->

                            <?=$item['related_id'];?>

                        </div>


                    </div>
                    <div class="nameprojectsumma">                        <!-- название приэкта и сумма  -->
                        <gg><a href="#"><?= $product->title; ?></a></gg>
                        <div class="summa">Цена:<?= $product->price; ?></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </section>

    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach ;?>
```

Comment: Непонятна связь между таблицами. И покажите желаемый результат на именно этих данных.

Comment: Результат : Объединение 2х таблиц, при выставлении значения "1" выводило значение с прикрепленной таблицы с индексом 1 только значение второго столбца в нашем примере это "Новый" .При выставлении значения "2" выводило значение "Старый".. У меня при любых индекса 1 или 2 или 3 выводит только "Новый"..

Comment: Понятнее не стало. У Вас показаны 2 таблицы, в первой 3 записи, во второй 2. Покажите таблицей, какой на именно таких данных нужен результат. PS. А PHP-код можете удалить - если возникнут проблемы с выводом полученного результата на страницу, то это будет совсем другой вопрос, который надо задавать отдельно.